# Spring Boot serving JSP pages out from resources folder?

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

Currently I am serving .jsp files from the traditional webapp folder

- resources
- webapp

  - WEB-INF

    - index.jsp

In my application properties I have set:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Is it possible to host the jsp files inside the **resources** folder in Spring Boot?

So far I had no success.

Cheers